# Setting interface name in /boo/config.txt

Tags: spi, config.txt, can-bus

I am trying to setup an interface name can1 (instead of can0) on spi0.

Looking at the instructions at https://blog.stabel.family/raspberry-pi-4-device-tree/ I was able to add a new overlay file. Even though I changed all references from can0 to can1, the interface is still named can0 after reboot.

What am I missing to have linux reference the interface as can1?

Here is my overlay named mcp2515-can1-spi0-overlay.dts:

```
/*
 * Device tree overlay for mcp251x/can1 on spi0.0
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
    /* disable spi-dev for spi0.0 */
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
    target = <&spidev0>;
    __overlay__ {
        status = "disabled";
    };
    };

    /* the interrupt pin of the can-controller */
    fragment@2 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            can1_pins: can1_pins {
                brcm,pins = <25>;
                brcm,function = <0>; /* input */
            };
        };
    };

    /* the clock/oscillator of the can-controller */
    fragment@3 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            /* external oscillator of mcp2515 on SPI0.0 */
            can1_osc: can1_osc {
                compatible = "fixed-clock";
                #clock-cells = <0>;
                clock-frequency  = <16000000>;
            };
        };
    };

    /* the spi config of the can-controller itself binding everything together */
    fragment@4 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            can1: mcp2515@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                compatible = "microchip,mcp2515";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&can1_pins>;
                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                interrupts = <25 8>; /* IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW */
                clocks = <&can1_osc>;
            };
        };
    };
    __overrides__ {
        oscillator = <&can1_osc>,"clock-frequency:0";
        spimaxfrequency = <&can1>,"spi-max-frequency:0";
        interrupt = <&can1_pins>,"brcm,pins:0",<&can1>,"interrupts:0";
    };
};
```

Here is my line in /boot/config.txt :

```
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can1-spi0,oscillator=12000000,interrupt=25,spimaxfrequency=2000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface name used by the kernel is not set by the dts.

Please see the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399676/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-label-in-a-linux-device-tree